# Otras formas de decir "mesh"

Tags: matemáticas

He oido la palabra "reticulado" en ambientes de ingeniería y matemáticas refiriéndose a elementos finitos.  Una vez escuché una investigación en donde utilizaron otra palabra, pero ya no me acuerdo cual fue.

¿Cuales son las formas correctas para decir "mesh" en el contexto de elementos finitos?

Comment: He escuchado redecilla y malla, pero no te podría decir la distinctión entre ellos por desconocerla yo.

Comment: Wikipedia en español usa *malla* https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_los_elementos_finitos

Comment: Como estudiante de matemáticas, yo siempre oí "malla".

Answer (score 4):

Por lo que he visto en programas de gráfica 3D, **mesh** se traduce normalmente como **malla**. Por ejemplo, *polymesh* es *malla poligonal*.

El **reticulado** que propones es una excelente traducción. Tal vez puedes considerar también **tejido** y **red**.

Comment: Diria no al ***red*** porque implica solamente las conecciones unidimensionales y discretos, mientras un mesh contiene todo el espacio alrededor y circunscritos por las conneciones.

Answer (score 2):

*Malla* o *mallado* son las formas que yo he oído. *Reticulado* está relacionada con *red* (de hecho tienen el mismo lexema), aunque esta solo la he oído en referencia a la estructura atómica de los sólidos (cristales).